Material3 PullToRefreshContainer not working
  fun ProductsListScreen() {
       
    
        val lazyListState: LazyGridState = rememberLazyGridState()
        var isRefreshing by remember {
            mutableStateOf(false)
        }
        val pullToRefreshState = rememberPullToRefreshState(enabled = { isRefreshing })
        val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    
        Scaffold(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), topBar = {
            ///topAppBar
    
        }) { paddingValues ->
    
            Box(
                Modifier
                    .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                    .nestedScroll(pullToRefreshState.nestedScrollConnection)
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(paddingValues)
            ) {
    
               
                    LazyVerticalGrid(
                        state = lazyListState,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .padding(10.dp)
                            .padding(bottom = paddingValues.calculateBottomPadding()),
                        columns = GridCells.Fixed(2),
                        contentPadding = PaddingValues(5.dp)
                    ) {
                       /// Items 
                    }
                
    
                if (pullToRefreshState.isRefreshing) {
                    LaunchedEffect(true) {
                        scope.launch {
                            isRefreshing = true
                            productViewModel.loadProducts(forceRefresh = true)
                            isRefreshing = false
                        }
                    }
                }
                LaunchedEffect(isRefreshing) {
                    if (isRefreshing) {
                        pullToRefreshState.startRefresh()
                    } else {
                        pullToRefreshState.endRefresh()
                    }
                }
    
                PullToRefreshContainer(
                    state = pullToRefreshState,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .align(Alignment.TopCenter),
                )
    
            }
    
        }
    
    
    }


I'm using composeBom version = "2024.04.01"

androidx-compose-bom = { group = "androidx.compose", name = "compose-bom", version.ref = "composeBom" }
androidx-material3 = { group = "androidx.compose.material3", name = "material3" }


I can see PullRefreshIndicator on top but it not pulling. I tried to use pullToRefreshState with LazyGrid and Box but no results. I tried to show an indicator from MainScreen by Unit function on ProductsScreen but also no result.


Please [edit] your question and replace your code with a [mre] that we can actually execute to reproduce the issue. Make sure the example is as short as possible. Also please specify the Material 3 version you are using (seems to be an old one, prior to 1.3.0) and if you are willing to upgrade.

The PullToRefreshContainer Composable has been replaced with PullToRefreshBox starting from material3:1.3.0. It was done in this commit and this file.
Your Compose BOM is deprecated and still using material3:1.2.1 internally. Please update your Compose BOM to the latest version, which as of 11/2024 is
composeBom = "2024.11.00"

Then, follow the sample in the documentation. The PullToRefreshBox must be the parent Composable of the scrolling content. Also, it will show a default indicator by itself:
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun ProductsListScreen() {

    val lazyGridState = rememberLazyGridState()
    var isRefreshing by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        topBar = {
            //...
        }
    ) { paddingValues ->

        PullToRefreshBox(
            isRefreshing = isRefreshing,
            onRefresh = {
                scope.launch {
                    isRefreshing = true
                    productViewModel.loadProducts(forceRefresh = true)
                    isRefreshing = false
                }
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(paddingValues)
        ) {

            LazyVerticalGrid(
                state = lazyGridState,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(10.dp)
                    .padding(bottom = paddingValues.calculateBottomPadding()),
                columns = GridCells.Fixed(2),
                contentPadding = PaddingValues(5.dp)
            ) {
                /// Items
            }
        }
    }
}

The PullToRefreshBox offers its own onRefresh callback, so you don't need to manually observe any PullToRefreshState.
